# WebPermission problem with GoDaddy hosting

Tags: web-hosting, asp.net, godaddy, iis7, iis

I purchased a Windows web host from `godaddy.com`.

When I want to use an email verification component (that wants to connect to the Internet) on my host, I get an error related to Web Permission denied (ASP.NET 4).

I searched for this error and found that GoDaddy has changed web permission in ASP.NET and restricts some features.  When I want to use components that require these web permission on my site, I get error 500 (Internal Server Error).

Can I give permission to an assembly only or solve my problem in another way?

I asked this question to the Godaddy support team, but I didn't get any answers.

Comment: You may ask GoDaddy to give full permission for you. But as I know Godaddy doesnt support Full Trust hosting. I would recommend you to find provider that offer Full Trust, for example asphostportal.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <trust level="Full" />
```

I tried this way, but did not affect.
I moved my site to another web hosting. The support team said me that their servers are in medium trust for hosting. if anyone wants full trust level, he should purchase VPS or Dedicated Server.

Answer (score 2):

[GoDaddy has a help page about web application trust level](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/2531/what-trust-level-can-i-use-when-running-aspnet).   It says that with ASP 4, you should be able to enable "full trust" with this directive in your Web.Config file:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <trust level="Full" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```